# Game Center Login Swift

Tags: swift, game-center

I am trying to integrate game center into my app.  I have spent lots of time trying to figure this out and need some help.  This is what I have so far:

```
func login() {
    println("login called")
    var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer()
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController: UIViewController!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if viewController != nil {
            println("VC True")
            self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }else if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated{

            //WHAT HERE?
        }
    }
}
```

I made a login function that I call in the view did load.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you get https://github.com/DaRkD0G/Easy-Game-Center-Swift ?

Comment: @YannickSteph above github link is not available

Answer (score 0):

You can use that, I create a simple class for iOS game center in github
https://github.com/DaRkD0G/Easy-Game-Center-Swift

Begin

```
import GameKit
/// The local player object.
let gameCenterPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
```

After in your func

```
    self.gameCenterPlayer.authenticateHandler={(var gameCenterVC:UIViewController!, var gameCenterError:NSError!) -> Void in

        if gameCenterVC != nil {
            self.presentViewController(gameCenterVC, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
                // no idea
            })
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Your Easy Game Center library returns an error at `EGC.printLogEGC("New delegate UIViewController is \(_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(newValue))\n")`. In other words, i can't access to EGC in my view controller. Thanks